# How to select right variable in java?

Tags: java

I very confusing about selecting the right variable on java in my current condition. for example I have this code:

```
A object1 = new A(){
    onUpdate(){
        B object2 = new B(){
            onStarted(){
                 this.setColor();
            }
        };
    }
};
```

the code is **only example** that describe my problem. the problem is

```
this.setColor();
```

"this" always point to object2. I want to "this" point to object1. how can I do that?

Comment: Good question but what is the need to code something like this?

Comment: `Object`, by itself, has no `setColor` method.  You'll want to provide some context to this object.

Comment: sory @Makoto, thats only example code. I'll edit my question..

Comment: I have another problem. what if I change my example code "this.setColor()" to "System.out.println(this)". how to make "this" point to object1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call

```
setColor
```

The correct method will be called given this method only exists in the "parent" class.

You could also try this:

```
public class Test{
    public void setColor(){}
    public class Test2{
        void onUpdate(){
            Test.this.setColor();
        }
    }    
}
```

Java docs review the latter solution [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 3):

You could do like this:

```
final A object1 = new A(){
    onUpdate(){
        B object2 = new B(){
            onStarted(){
                 object1.setColor();
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Because `this` is inside `B` it's normal for `this` to refer to the current instance of `B`.

Also note that for this to work `object1` has to be `final`.

Comment: no, I have a reason to select "this" instead of object1. but thanks for your reply, I have a right answer from @William Morrisson

Comment: This doesn't work. The method setColor is not defined for class Object obviously.

Comment: Uhm as I understand @ForoTesto just want to give an example and accidentally he use the Object class ^.^ ... I'll edit my answer then. Let's call class A or Class B and we don't know exactly what those classes contained. So ...

Comment: @Van Vu: hard to explain. 
I have tried your code, but it doesn't work.
once again thank you for your answer

Comment: @William Morrisson: that code is only example, yeah Van Vu right, I accidentally use the Object class ^.^

Comment: Ah, I apologize. I should be more lax, humans aren't compilers after all!

Comment: @WilliamMorrison We devs think more and more like a machine now. My wife complained me that I could not handle illogical question ... have a nice day